# What are some good (legal) resources for finding the text of books?

Tags: support, faq, quotations

Many good answers on this site are going to require quoting passages of the text of a novel, poem, play, or other piece of literature. Thus, knowing where to find such passages is going to be very important for the site's users in composing their answers.

Copying them out by hand from paper books works, but is slow and tiring. Finding pirated texts online probably also works (I've never tried), but we don't want to encourage that here. So:

### what are some good, legal, online resources for finding texts to quote?

I'll post a community-wiki answer to this question which anyone can edit. Let's try to get a really good list all in one place so that we can refer people to it in the future.

Comment: Do you mean to ask about free resources? I infer from the sites you included in your answer that you were, but I don't see the word "free" in your question (unless I just missed it). Would https://amazon.com/ work in an answer? That site satisfies "good," "legal," and "online."

Comment: Related administrative note regarding resource lists on meta - https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/142 - Should this be moved to the main site?

Comment: I think that clearly suggests we should move this to the main site.

Comment: @Chenmunka Ah, but I'm not just asking for a random list of literature-relevant resources: I'm trying to set up a resource which will **help people with writing posts on Literature.SE**. That's what meta is for. (This is why I was careful to include that 2nd sentence in my question.)

Comment: It would be helpful if we could just get guidance to be sure.

Comment: @Benjamin Does [this](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/57) count as guidance? :-)

Comment: No, not really because the advice there is coming from an admin.

Comment: @Benjamin Well, you've got my comment above explaining why I think this should stay on meta, and a mod of this site who clearly agrees. I'm not sure what else you want. We can't call in a CM for every little meta issue.

Comment: If this question exists, it can't exist on the main site, because it would be closed as a recommendation question. Should the question be allowed on meta? I don't really care, but I could go either way.

Comment: Reasoning for why this should stay here: 1.) It doesn't belong on the main site. It would be closed as either too broad, because it's an open-ended list question, or off-topic, as a recommendation question. 2.) It's designed for helping *this community* in their efforts *on this site*. (cc @Benjamin)

Comment: @Mithrandir I think I now agree.

Comment: @Shokhet (Sorry, I must have missed your comment at first.) I think I'd like to focus on free resources if possible, since you can get nearly any book reasonably easily if you're willing to pay for it, and I doubt many people will be willing to spend money *just* to write answers on SE. But if enough people think a non-free section in the CW answer would be useful, then by all means add one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Sites which cover many books

- [**Project Gutenberg**](https://www.gutenberg.org/) has tens of thousands of public domain texts. [**Project Gutenberg Australia**](http://gutenberg.net.au/) and [**Project Gutenberg Canada**](https://gutenberg.ca/index.html) sometimes have texts that their US cousin does not, due to different copyright terms in the three countries.
- [**Google Books**](https://books.google.com/) has the full text of many public domain books, and generous previews of copyrighted books are also available, though these tend to be in noncontiguous chunks of pages.
- The [**Internet Archive**](https://archive.org/) has many scans of books: those in public domain are freely accessible; those in copyright are available for loan.
- [**Wikisource**](https://wikisource.org/) has many public domain texts in [English](https://en.wikisource.org/), [French](https://fr.wikisource.org/), [German](https://de.wikisource.org/), [Hebrew](https://he.wikisource.org/) and other languages.
- The **British Library** has a large collection of [digitized manuscripts](https://www.bl.uk/manuscripts/).
- [**Goodreads**](https://www.goodreads.com/) provides previews of books, often quite lengthy, making this site perfect if you are looking for something in the first few chapters. It also collects user-contributed reviews and plot summaries.
- For [poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) questions, [**Poetry Foundation**](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/) has a large collection of poems. The site also carries biographical and critical essays on several poets.
- [**Luminarium**](http://www.luminarium.org/) provides an anthology of English literature covering four periods: the Middle Ages, the Renaissance, the seventeenth century and the Restoration.
- [**Loyal Books**](http://www.loyalbooks.com), formerly known as "Books Should Be Free", provides a collection of public domain audio books and e-books.
- [**Sacred Texts**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/index.htm) provides the full texts of assorted books of religion, mythology, and folklore.
- [**Faded Page**](https://www.fadedpage.com/) hosts an archive of over 5,000 ebooks.
- [**The Hathi Trust**](https://www.hathitrust.org/) "is a partnership of academic and research institutions, offering a collection of millions of titles digitized from libraries around the world." The catalog features are more convenient than the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/), but access speed can be painfully slow.
- [**Tor.com**](https://www.tor.com/category/all-fiction/) has hundreds of short stories and novelettes, and sometimes makes novels available as part of marketing campaigns.
- The "Look inside" feature at [**Amazon.com**](https://amazon.com/) shows sample pages from many of the products on sale. In some cases the search box at top left will show pages beyond the sample.
- [**Hypertexts (XRoads)**](https://web.archive.org/web/20191023135142/http://xroads.virginia.edu/%7EHYPER/hypertex.html) at the University of Virginia formerly hosted texts by American writers, including Edgar Allan Poe, Mark Twain, and F. Scott Fitzgerald. (Preserved via web.archive.org.)
- [**eBooks@Adelaide**](https://web.archive.org/web/20191215153342/https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/) at the University of Adelaide formerly hosted public domain texts of academic interest. (Preserved via web.archive.org.)
- Many public libraries make eBooks available to members as part of the library benefits. Typically, eBooks can be checked out from the library's website by any cardholder.

#### Sites for texts in specific languages

- [**Early English Books Online**](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebogroup/) has a searchable corpus of printed works in English from 1475 to 1700.
- For [french-language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french-language) [**Gallica**](https://gallica.bnf.fr) is the online archive for the Bibliothèque nationale de France.
- For [german-language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-language) [**Deutsche Digitale Bibliothek**](https://www.deutsche-digitale-bibliothek.de) catalogs digitized books from across Germany. [**Projekt Gutenberg-DE**](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/index.html) offers mainly literature in German.
- For [greek-language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek-language) and [latin-language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-language) the [**Perseus Digital Library**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/) covers the history, literature and culture of the Greco-Roman world.
- For [hungarian-language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hungarian-language) [**Magyar Elektronikus Könyvtár**](http://mek.niif.hu/) or [**MEK**](http://mek.oszk.hu/) collects many fiction and non-fiction books, some in public domain, and some copyrighted but  displayed on the site with permission.  Also includes a few audiobooks by Magyar Vakok és Gyengénlátók Országos Szövetsége.
- For [italian-language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italian-language), [**progetto Manuzio of Liber Liber**](https://liberliber.it/opere/libri/) has lot of free downloadable ebooks.
- For [latin-language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-language), the [**Packard Humanities Institute**](https://latin.packhum.org/) has a searchable corpus of Latin literary prose from antiquity.
- For [old-english-language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-english-language) the entire corpus of poetry is available at the [**Sacred Texts**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/ascp/index.htm) site. Translations of nearly all these poems are available from [**Aaron K. Hostetter**](https://oldenglishpoetry.camden.rutgers.edu) and spoken versions of the poems from [**Michael Drout**](http://mdrout.webspace.wheatoncollege.edu). [**In Parentheses**](http://www.yorku.ca/inpar/) has some translations as well. [**Old English Poetry in Facsimile**](https://oepoetryfacsimile.org) has digitized manuscripts with critical apparatus.
- For [russian-language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-language) and some others, [**ЛитРес (LitRes)**](https://www.litres.ru/) is an online bookstore which has many books, mostly [Russian classics](https://www.litres.ru/kollekcii-knig/besplatnie-knigi/). For example, the whole [strugatsky-brothers](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strugatsky-brothers) collection is there, free of charge.
- For [sanskrit-language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sanskrit-language), [**Sanskrit Documents**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/sitemap/) has a large collection of Vedic, classical, and modern texts, as well as a [**listing**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/TextsElsewhere/) of other sites with texts in that language.
- For [scandinavian-language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scandinavian-language) [**handrit.is**](https://handrit.is/) catalogs digitized manuscripts at libraries in Iceland, Denmark and Sweden.
- For poetry in [urdu-language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urdu-language) or [hindustani-language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hindustani-language), [**Rekhta**](https://rekhta.org/) provides original texts, transliterations in the Roman script, and translations of specific words in mouseover. The site also has digitized [over 100,000 books](https://rekhta.org/ebooks/web) encompassing poetry, translation, biography, history, and criticism. The vast majority are in Urdu, but many are in Hindi and some in English. Free registration is required beyond limited access.

#### Sites for specific books or authors

- For the epics by [homer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homer), the [**Chicago Homer**](https://homer.library.northwestern.edu/splash.html) has full texts in the original Ancient Greek with interlinear English translations.
- For the [divine-comedy](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divine-comedy) by [dante-alighieri](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dante-alighieri), the [**Dartmouth Dante Project**](https://dante.dartmouth.edu).
- For [geoffrey-chaucer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoffrey-chaucer):

  - [**Chaucer Metasite**](https://chaucermetapage.org/old/chtexts.htm) has electronic full texts of many (all?) of his works
  - [**Harvard University**](https://chaucer.fas.harvard.edu/pages/text-and-translations) has the original text and line-by-line translations for [the-canterbury-tales](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-canterbury-tales) specifically.
- For [samuel-johnson](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samuel-johnson), the [**Yale Digital Edition**](http://www.yalejohnson.com/frontend/).
- For [h-p-lovecraft](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/h-p-lovecraft):

  - [**hplovecraft.com**](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/) has the full text of each story in easily copy-pastable format
  - [**Arkham Archivist**](http://arkhamarchivist.com/), formerly known as Cthulhu Chick, has collected his complete works in a single document which you can download for free in various formats.
- For [edgar-allan-poe](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edgar-allan-poe), [**poestories.com**](http://poestories.com/stories.php) has the full text of some selected stories in HTML form.
- For [william-shakespeare](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/william-shakespeare):

  - [**this excellent site from MIT**](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/index.html) has the full text of all his plays;
  - [**Open Source Shakespeare**](http://opensourceshakespeare.org/)
  - [**Internet Shakespeare Editions**](http://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/Foyer/plays/)
  - [**The Oxford Shakespeare**](http://www.bartleby.com/70/) on Bartleby.com provides the 1914 Oxford edition.
  - [**The Folger Shakespeare Library**](https://shakespeare.folger.edu) is a renowned source of Shakespeare scholarship. Their website includes full and reliable texts of his poems and plays.
- For [sherlock-holmes](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sherlock-holmes), [**sherlockian.net**](http://www.sherlockian.net/investigating/canon/) has collections of links for each story—not just the full text of the story but also lots of surrounding information—as well as many non-Doyle 'fanfic' stories.
- For [the-wind-in-the-willows](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-wind-in-the-willows), try the [**Cleave Books**](http://www.cleavebooks.co.uk/grol/grahame/wind00.htm) site.
- For [strugatsky-brothers](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strugatsky-brothers):

  - [**this semi-official page**](http://www.rusf.ru/abs/english/) hosts only four books now, but they are official, and seem to be updated when a new book is available for free download.
  - Its Russian counterpart officially hosts all of [**their books**](http://www.rusf.ru/abs/books0.htm).
- For [the-bible](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-bible) and other Jewish texts:

  - [**Sefaria**](http://www.sefaria.org/) has the Jewish Bible with a crowdsourced translation and also [**the JPS translation**](https://blog.sefaria.org/2016/06/15/the-jps-1985-tanakh-translation-is-now-on-sefaria/). There are a lot of useful features, including the ability to link to an individual verse instead of a whole chapter, alternate translations, and integration with traditional Jewish commentaries.
  - [**Chabad.org**](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8165) and [**Mechon Mamre**](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0.htm) also have the Bible with translations, but Sefaria is the easiest, best looking, and most feature-rich of the three.
  - All of these are also compatible with the [**Mi Yodeya Referencer**](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1758/5323), which works on all SE sites.
- A translation of the first four branches of [the-mabinogion](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-mabinogion) is available at [**mabinogi.net**](http://www.mabinogi.net/)

#### Please help add to and improve this answer!

That's why I've made it CW - this is a community resource, so let's all muck in and help to create it.

Comment: Please don't add links to this answer unless that you are 100% sure they are legal and not pirated.

Comment: You can search the full text of copyrighted works at [Google Books](https://books.google.com/) and [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/), but I don't know if those are the sort of resource you're looking for. The excerpts are sometimes all you need, or they may be enough to decide whether it's worth paying a visit to your local library for a specific book.

Comment: I've found [this website](https://www.defectivebydesign.org/guide/ebooks), which lists numerous platforms that are either libraries or shopping platforms. I'll take a stroll through it later and add the good ones.

Comment: I'm not sure if this warrants an edit to this post, but you should check with your local library. You might not be aware, but many have ebooks available for "loan." Yours might, too.

Comment: Tor.com Publishing [has hundreds of short stories and novelettes available for free on its site](http://www.tor.com/category/all-fiction/) and will often also make entire ebooks available for limited times as part of marketing campaigns.

Comment: @BESW Why not edit instead of commenting? That's why this post is CW :-)

Comment: I've copied @BESW's comment into the answer.

Comment: Also @Shokhet's

Comment: Thanks @verbose! You've done so much work on this answer that the little grey CW box in the bottom right now shows your username instead of mine :-D

Comment: @Randal'Thor The way they calculate is odd. I wrote very little. I did move a bunch of stuff around and restructured/reformatted the answer. 70%+ of the answer is *not* by me.

Comment: @verbose Very odd, I don't know what algorithm they use to calculate it. Maybe it's because you added/changed some links and the system counts that as deleting and re-adding lots of stuff even though it's just moving (see the revision history, there's tons of red and green text).

Comment: Oh! Yes, the links were inconsistent. Some were [in this format](with the URL in parentheses), others used [this format][1] and I turned them all into the latter for consistency's sake.

[1] link down below

Comment: @verbose That's because different people were editing the answer. I always use the [text](link) format, because I don't like scrolling all the way to the bottom to find the link, but some other editors added lots of things the [text][1] format. Oh well, I agree with you that consistency is better.

Comment: @Randal'Thor heh when editing the answer the reason I used the [text][1] format was that it was too much trouble to scroll down to grab each link and convert it to [text](link), whereas converting the latter into the former was much easier.