# Announcing the May 2017 topic challenge: Icelandic Sagas!

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our meta agreement to have [topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/11), seeing that the votes have [stabilised](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/649/timeline), April is nearing its end, and it's time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **May 2017**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/649/11) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor), will be

> ### Topic challenge: Icelandic Sagas
>
> I think suggesting a single one would be too narrow a challenge to catch many people's interest, but [Icelandic sagas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagas_of_Icelanders) as a whole definitely form an interesting (and influential) part of literature. I don't know *too* much about them, but some rudimentary research suggests that they started off as [oral-tradition](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oral-tradition)s in the 9th to 11th centuries and an evolved form of them was written down a few centuries later. Having a topic challenge about these might help to [educate people](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/does-oral-literature-count-as-literature-here#comment2265_638) about oral literature.
>
> Although they are part of European culture, they still originate in a non-English-speaking country, and I think they count as **broadening the cultural scope of the site**; after all, we don't have any questions about [icelandic-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icelandic-literature) yet. Being centuries old, of course, they're also **freely available online**, including in English translations - for example at the [Icelandic Saga Database](http://sagadb.org/)

As with the previous announcement, I post this before the actual start of the challenge, so that everyone has time to prepare. The topic challenge will start on May 1st.

---

**What is a topic challenge?**

During a topic challenge, community members read and ask questions about a particular topic.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/701/11) of our history.

Question on other topics are always welcome as well, but they won't count as a part of this challenge.

**How does one participate?**

To participate in this topic challenge, all one has to do is ask or answer a question related to Icelandic sagas. That simple! Questions asked in the scope of this topic challenge should be tagged with [scandinavian-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scandinavian-literature) or [norse-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norse-literature), as appropriate (see tagging discussion [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/692/17)).

[Icelandic Saga Database](http://sagadb.org/) (props to Rand al'Thor) has a collection of sagas available for download in multiple formats; also check [this thread](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/653/11) for places to find reading resources.

**What else?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/11) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!
- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/692/11) on the tagging for Scandinavian/Nordic literature questions!
- [Add](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/653/11) resources with freely and legally available reading!

Comment: Formatting shamelessly copied from [Rand al'Thor's post](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/650/).

Comment: If anyone's confused as to why this was announced so early, it's so people have time to find a copy or dust one off before the challenge starts.

Comment: Are we going to be at risk of duplicates with Mythology.SE?

Comment: @DVK Which is even funnier given that [our answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295163/348200) on main meta is right below theirs :D

Comment: See also https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/263/197 "Myth of the Month #1: Gylfaginning" on Mythology SE meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **List of [all questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bscandinavian-literature%5D%20created%3A2017-05-01..2017-05-31%20is%3Aquestion) asked as a part of this challenge:**

- [What is a beacon?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2468/what-is-a-beacon) by [Hamlet](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/111/hamlet)
- [Why is there so much legalese in Egil's Saga?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2472/why-is-there-so-much-legalese-in-egils-saga) by [Matt Thrower](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/129/matt-thrower)
- **far too few** `:-(`

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Why is there so much legalese in Egil's Saga?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2472/17), with a score of **7** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** is [What is a beacon?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2468/17), with approximately **70** views during the month.

Each question received exactly one answer.